# Fatal error: Call to undefined function in file.php error / defined function

Tags: php, undefined-function

I have a site which is developed in 2007. I have been using this website with no problem, but recently I am having a php error like below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getTitle() in comments.php error on line 3

$ptitle = htmlspecialchars(getTitle($row_cs['id'])); // line 3
```

This function is defined in funcs.php file.

Below is how I used the files with include;

### index.php

```
include 'funcs.php'
...
...
...
include 'comments.php'
```

### funcs.php

```
function getTitle($tid)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select title from table where id = '".$tid."'");
    $title = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

    return $title[0];
}
```

I am calling `getTitle()` method in comments.php.
I am not directly including funcs.php in comments.php
Both files (funcs.php and comments.php) are included in index.php. And I was normally using a funcs.php method in comments.php file.

Why am I getting this error recently, is this a server configuration issue?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: show the code where getTitle() is being called

Comment: you need to show the code for both where the function is defined and where the function is called

Comment: Make up your mind, mate. Is your error "Call to undefined function" or is it "Call to a member function on non-object"?

Comment: sorry for that, I have just tried to convert to an object and then call from this object. But this made no difference, just the error message changed. I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you please post the function declaration code AND the line where you call the function?

Comment: added function declaration and the line where the function called.

Answer (score 0):

Please use single quote to include the files.

```
include 'func.php';
include 'comments.php';
```

Comment: in php files, the quotes are included. this code was working, recently I am getting this error. nothing changed in codes. thanks.